# Customised QThread is possible?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, qtgui, qt4.7

I Want Qt with xenomai patch.So i want to inherit QThread, inside QThread pthread functions will call for Linux. I want to replace with Xenomai RT_TASK. Is it possible?

Comment: You overcomplicated your question with something that most of people here have no idea about. But yes, customized QThread is possible and if you willing to express your question more abstract then somebody will likely come up with solution. And what accuracy is in this context?

Comment: Accuracy in the sense i want to know if QTimer i will start in time critical mode with 1ms it will work or not?? Inside QTimer QThread only will call. What is minimum time we run a QTimer. Its looking like a small question. But if we need time critical condition code development the answer will reduce the code size and provide modularity

Comment: Thanks AlexanderVX. Now I'm asking in straight forward.

Comment: No idea of xenomai. For high resolution timer for Linux QTimer is not an adequate solution as long as Linux is not RTOS. Google "Linux high resolution timer".